# iPhone Text Field>Format Input String as a Credit Card Number As They Type

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring

How can I format a users text field input as they type and insert a "-" or " " on every 5th character.

4500000000000000 becomes 4500 0000 0000 0000

Comment: Duplicate of [Formatting a UITextField for credit card input like (xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12083605/formatting-a-uitextfield-for-credit-card-input-like-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a delegate for your text field, then implement `-textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` to update the text field whenever the user types / pastes anything.