# How to assign a set of methods to UITextFieldDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I want to know how to fire a method when a particular text box is edited.

For example, it is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12083605) how to assign a certain format to a textbox, using a number of functions. However, I don't know where to copy-paste these functions. In the explanation it says to use `UITextFieldDelegate`, but I don't know where it is.

I have a `AppDelegate` class, a `ViewController` class (including its xib), and a `UITextField` in the xib. I want the code to work for this UITextField.

Comment: You basically need to understand the concept of [protocols](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html) better. Most likely, your view controller would implement the UITextFieldDelegate. Be sure to set your view controller as the delegate for the UITextField in the XIB as well. (I had a longer answer before the question was put on hold.)

Comment: @ jxpx777 thanks for ur answer. Could u please explain more. Do u mean that when I drag a textfield, the method should be automatically generated? I did not understand the third sentence too. Thanks again.

Comment: Control+click and drag from your text field to the view controller's icon in interface builder and set the delegate there. Then, your view controller is set as the delegate and you need to manually add the UITextFieldDelegate protocol methods to your view controller so they are there when the text field tries to call them at run time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add those methods in your ViewController.m class
and then in your viewDidLoad method of ViewController.m Class

```
[yourTextField addTarget:yourTextFieldDelegate 
                             action:@selector(reformatAsCardNumber:)
                   forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

set `reformatCardNumber`: to be called whenever the text field fires a `UIControlEventEditingChanged` event

also add delegete in Viewcontroller.h file 
and Thats Done.

Comment: thanks a lot for ur answer. I have one more question. How can I get the name of my text field? I have 2 textfields and I want this method to be applied to both of them.

Comment: just register both text box with the textboxname.delegete=self and you will have that method fired whenever textbox will change value

Comment: @ Bhavik Kama : Thanks a gain. 1) are u sure I should exactly write  textboxname.delegete=self inside the viewcontroller.m? Because I actually dont know how to get the name of the textfield. 2) Could u please explain why it would work? here self refers to the viewcontroller? what does textboxname.delegete=self exactly mean? Thanks again.

Comment: Assign two different tags to both text box using tag property. Inside you delegate method check for tags you have defined.

Comment: actually you need to explore more For Objective c Language.. you dont know the basic things.. so better find some tutorial and have some basic knowledge of the Objective c