# Add slash to string every n characters

Tags: string, swift, string-formatting

How do to add a forward slash to a string every n characters? 
For example:

```
"123456" -> "123/456/"
"1234567" -> "123/456/7"
```

Without adding a string extension

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34454532/how-add-separator-to-string-at-every-n-characters-in-swift

Comment: Without a using a (string) extension!

Comment: there is another answers check that

Comment: ... and also every extension method can easily be made a global function.

Comment: @MDaniyal: Re your edit suggestion: Backticks are for `code`, not for general emphasis.