# insert a character inside an Int Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a number, I want to insert a column ":" between each two consecutive digits inside that number, and get a String as a result

For example:

```
let number: Int = 34567  
let result: String = "3:4:5:6:7"
```

Thanks for any help,

Comment: Wouldn't "Colon between each two digits" be "34:56:7"? what have you tried already?

Comment: `let result = String(number).map({String($0)}).joined(separator: ":")`?

Comment: it is between two consecutive digits, I have just corrected it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How add separator to string at every N characters in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34454532/how-add-separator-to-string-at-every-n-characters-in-swift)

Answer (score 6):

Possible solution:

```
let result = String(number).map({ String($0) }).joined(separator: ":")
```

With explanation of intermediary results to help understand what's going on on theses 3 chained methods:

```
let interemdiary1 = String(number)
print("interemdiary1: \(interemdiary1)")
let interemdiary2 = interemdiary1.map({ String($0 )})
print("interemdiary2: \(interemdiary2)")
let interemdiary3 = interemdiary2.joined(separator: ":")
print("interemdiary3: \(interemdiary3)")
```

Output:

```
$>interemdiary1: 34567
$>interemdiary2: ["3", "4", "5", "6", "7"]
$>interemdiary3: 3:4:5:6:7
```

First, let's transform your `number` into a String.
Then, let's create an array of it where each character (as a `String`) of the previous result is an element of it. I used a `map()` of it.
Finally, we use `joined(separator:)` to assemble them.

Another kind of solution can be found there:
[How add separator to string at every N characters in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34454532/how-add-separator-to-string-at-every-n-characters-in-swift) It's just that you do it each 1 characters.

Answer (score 1):

You need to join it by `:`

use this

```
let result = String(number).map({String($0)}).joined(separator: ":")
```