# Swift - Format textfield for a credit card

Tags: ios, swift, textfield, credit-card

I've been stuck on this for awhile now and I was wondering what is the best way to format a textfield for a credit card type format?

Comment: this is an opinion based question... no general answer possible... also please provide more code and what you have tryed so far and what isn't working or does not what you're expecting it to do. stackoverflow is no coding service.

Comment: the next time you feel like stuck on a problem, use google,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12083605/formatting-a-uitextfield-for-credit-card-input-like-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Caishen](https://github.com/prolificinteractive/Caishen) framework.

It updates the contents of the textfield after every edit using this function :

```
public func formattedCardNumber(cardNumberString: String) -> String {
        let regex: NSRegularExpression

        let cardType = cardTypeRegister.cardTypeForNumber(Number(rawValue: cardNumberString))
        do {
            let groups = cardType.numberGrouping
            var pattern = ""
            var first = true
            for group in groups {
                pattern += "(\\d{1,\(group)})"
                if !first {
                    pattern += "?"
                }
                first = false
            }
            regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: NSRegularExpressionOptions())
        } catch {
            fatalError("Error when creating regular expression: \(error)")
        }

        return NSArray(array: self.splitString(cardNumberString, withRegex: regex)).componentsJoinedByString(self.separator)
    }
```